# Remove all but two fields in EXIF data of a jpeg image using C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, exif

I am using C# and the ImageFactory library (from ImageProcessor.org) to greatly modify a jpg image.  It does straightening, cropping, shadow detail enhancement, etc. .

It is fully working and successfully writes the new image to a file.
But this file contains the original EXIF data, most of which is now incorrect or irrelevant.

I definitely need to keep the orientation flag in the EXIF data, as it is needed to correctly orient the modified image.  And I want to keep the DateTime.  But all the other EXIF data should go away.

I can find ways to add or modify an EXIF propertyitem in the image metadata, but no way to remove one.

```
     using (ImageFactory ifact = new ImageFactory()) {
        ifact.PreserveExifData = true;
        ifact.Load(edat.ImageFilename);

        // save the image in a bitmap that will be manipulated
        //ifact.PreserveExifData = false;  // tried this but b1 still had EXIF data
        Bitmap b1 = (Bitmap)ifact.Image;

        //lots of processsing here...

        // write the image to the output file
        b1.Save(outfilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      }
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample of what you have now, it will be easier to work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to remove **all** unwanted EXIF tags.

Those that remain may also be modified.

```
  // remove unneeded EXIF data
  using (ImageFactory ifact = new ImageFactory()) {
    ifact.PreserveExifData = true;
    ifact.Load(ImageFilename);
    // IDs to keep: model, orientation, DateTime, DateTimeOriginal
    List<int> PropIDs = new List<int>(new int[] { 272, 274, 306, 36867 });
    // get the property items from the image
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, PropertyItem> EXIF_Dict = ifact.ExifPropertyItems;
    List<int> foundList = new List<int>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, PropertyItem> kvp in EXIF_Dict) foundList.Add(kvp.Key);
    // remove EXIF tags unless they are in the PropIDs list
    foreach (int id in foundList) {
      PropertyItem junk;
      if (!PropIDs.Contains(id)) {
        // the following line removes a tag
        EXIF_Dict.TryRemove(id, out junk);
      }
    }
    // change the retained tag's values here if desired
    EXIF_Dict[274].Value[0] = 1;
    // save the property items back to the image
    ifact.ExifPropertyItems = EXIF_Dict;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Test\\test.jpg");

foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem item in bmp.PropertyItems)
{
    if (item.Id == 0x0112 || item.Id == 0x0132)
        continue;

    System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem modItem = item;
    modItem.Value = new byte[]{0};
    bmp.SetPropertyItem(modItem);
}

bmp.Save("C:\\Test\\noexif.jpg");
```

Here's the Id table for reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id(v=vs.110).aspx

`0x0112` - Orientation

`0x0132` - Date/Time

Comment: 270  ImageDescription:      System.String
 271  Make:        System.String
 272  Model:        System.String
 274  Orientation:  6     System.UInt16
 306  DateTime:  2018:01:04 08:03:13 System.String
 36864 ExifVersion:  0     System.Byte
 36867 DateTimeOriginal:      System.String
 36868 DateTimeDigitized:      System.String
 37121 ComponentsConfiguration:  0  System.Byte
 37500 MakerNote:   0    System.Byte
 37510 UserComment:  0    System.Byte
 40960 FlashpixVersion:  0    System.Byte
 41728 FileSource:   0    System.Byte

Comment: Excellent start !   (Sorry above comment posted accidentally.)  There are several extra fields still present, but their contents are mostly blank or zero.  I'll see if I can find a way to make them disappear as well.  All values still present are listed next.  ImageDescription  Make Model  Orientation:6 DateTime:2018:01:04 08:03:13 ExifVersion:0  DateTimeOriginal  DateTimeDigitized ComponentsConfiguration:0 MakerNote:0  UserComment:0 FlashpixVersion:0  FileSource:0

Answer (score 1):

I used `RemovePropertyItem` instead of `SetPropertyItem` like this:

```
private Image RemoveGpsExifInfo(Image image)
{
  foreach (var item in image.PropertyItems)
  {
    // GPS range is from 0x0000 to 0x001F. Full list here -> https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html (click on GPS tags)
    if (item.Id <= 0x001F)
    {
      image.RemovePropertyItem(item.Id);
    }
  }

  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Image Object input solutions provided here.
however there are some exception in reading Image object properties

I modified solution into a pure byte array based function, and its reusable.
if type is not image then return same array of bytes

```
public static byte[] GetGeoInfoRemovedImage(byte[] buffer, ILogger logger)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                using (var img = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
                {
                    foreach (var item in img.PropertyItems)
                    {
                        // GPS range is from 0x0000 to 0x001F
                        if (item.Id <= 0x001F)
                        {
                            img.RemovePropertyItem(item.Id);
                        }
                    }
                    MemoryStream memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream();
                    img.Save(memoryStream1, img.RawFormat);
                    byte[] buffer2 = memoryStream1.ToArray();
                    return buffer2;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogWarning(ex.Message); //Could not strip out geo info
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```